# SwiftUI - Subclassed viewModel doesn't trigger view refresh

Tags: swiftui

I have this situation where I have a a `BaseView` containing some common elements and a `BaseViewModel` containing some common functions, but when its `@Published` var get updated no `BaseView` refresh occurs.

The setup is this:

```
class BaseViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var overlayView: AnyView = EmptyView().convertToAnyView()

    func forceViewRefresh() {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }

    func setOverlayView(overlayView: AnyView) {
        self.overlayView = overlayView
    }

}
```

This view model subclasses `BaseViewModel`:

```
class FirstViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    func showOverlayView() {
        self.setOverlayView(overlayView: OverlayView().convertToAnyView())
    }
}
```

also I have a `BaseView` where I use the `overlayView`

```
struct BaseView<Content: View>: View {

let content: Content
@ObservedObject var viewModel = BaseViewModel()

init(content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
}

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
        content
        viewModel.overlayView
    }
    
}
```

}

The first view that gets displayed is `FirstView`, which conforms to a `BaseViewProtocol` and has a `FirstViewModel` that extends `BaseViewModel`.

```
struct FirstView: BaseViewProtocol {

@ObservedObject var viewModel = FirstViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    BaseView() {
        
        Button("Show overlay") {
            viewModel.showOverlayView()
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Clicking the `Show overlay` button in `First View` calls the  `showOverlayView()` func on `FirstViewModel` which in turn calls `setOverlayView` on the `BaseViewModel`. The value of `overlayView` in `BaseViewModel` changes as expected, but no view refresh on `FirstView` is called.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `@Published var overlayView: AnyView = EmptyView().convertToAnyView()`? This is not how SwiftUI is supposed to work... Please share more code so we can help you more.

Comment: I am setting up an overlayView in the BaseViewModel in order for it to be displayed in the layout by any other view whose viewmodel subclasses BaseViewModel. When the published var changes from a default empty view to another view it should trigger a view refresh but it doesnt't. I don't see anything that goes against how SwiftUI "works". (btw convertToAnyView is just a small extension I wrote and it's basically equivalent to AnyView(overlayView)).

Comment: However, I have edited the original post adding more details to better focus the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this code sample and works fine on Xcode 12 beta 6 & iOS 14 beta 8

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FirstViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: { viewModel.showOverlayView() }) {
                Text("Press")
            }
            viewModel.overlayView
        }
    }
}

class BaseViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var overlayView: AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
    
    func forceViewRefresh() {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
    
    func setOverlayView(overlayView: AnyView) {
        self.overlayView = overlayView
    }
    
}

class FirstViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    func showOverlayView() {
        self.setOverlayView(
            overlayView: AnyView(
                Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.2)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in SwiftUI you don't create views in outside the `body`. The view creation should be left to SwiftUI - instead you can define some other controls telling SwiftUI *how* and *when* to create a view.

Here is a simplified demo how to present different overlays for different views.

You can create a basic OverlayView:

```
enum OverlayType {
    case overlay1, overlay2
}

struct OverlayView: View {
    let overlayType: OverlayType

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if overlayType == .overlay1 {
            Text("Overlay1") // can be replaced with any view you want
        }
        if overlayType == .overlay2 {
            Text("Overlay1")
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in your BaseView (if `overlayType` is `nil` the overlay will not be shown):

```
struct BaseView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let overlayType: OverlayType?
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            content()
            if overlayType != nil {
                OverlayView(overlayType: overlayType!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the ContentView you can use the BaseView and specify its OverlayType.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var overlayType: OverlayType?

    var body: some View {
        BaseView(overlayType: overlayType) {
            Button("Show overlay") {
                overlayType = .overlay1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some considerations:

- For simplicity I used `@State` variables to control overlays. If there are other use cases for your ViewModels you may want to move the logic there.
- Note that instead of `AnyView` it's preferred to use `@ViewBuilder`.
- Also if you want to observe an `ObservableObject` inside a view, you need to use `@ObservedObject`, not `@ObservableObject`.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good approach, I'll give it a try. Also thanks for the final suggestions, even though the @ObservedObject issue was just a typo on my behalf :-)

Comment: Anyway the main issue in my code is that the BaseView does not refresh when the published overlay var gets updated. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @Goblin Just don’t create views manually outside the body (except when in SceneDelegate) and you won’t have these issues - as I explained in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Right, but the overlay are dynamic and not known at runtime, so creating them beforehand is not feasible. And even if I knew them, what if I have like 50 different overlays? Endless enums?

Comment: @Goblin This is just an example. But with your current approach what will happen if you have 50 different overlays? 50 ViewModels? 50 functions? And if overlays are *dynamic and not known at runtime* then why didn't you mention this in the question?

Comment: Because that wasn't the main focus of the question. The real problem is that when the published var in BaseViewModel changes it doesn't refresh the view. This is the issue I'd like to resolve, the rest, I can take care of later.